# Integrating $\int \sin^3(a x)dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have to integrate the following, where a is a constant:

$$I=\int \sin^3(a x)dx$$

I did the following:
$$u=ax$$
$$\frac{du}{a}=dx$$

Which gets me to this point:

$$\frac{1}{a}\int(1-\cos^2(u))\sin u \ du$$

Then I did u-substitution again and got it to this point:

$$g= \cos u$$
$$-dg=\sin u\ du$$

$$I=-\frac{1}{a}\int(1-g^2)dg$$
$$I=-\frac{1}{a}[g-\frac{g^3}{3}]+C$$
$$I=\frac{1}{a}[\frac{\cos^3(ax)}{3}-\cos(ax)]+C$$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: You mean $d\theta$ where you wrote $dx$?

Comment: This looks correct.

Comment: or $x$ where you wrote $\theta$ ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I fixed it.

Comment: You, personally, can check indefinite integrals!  Strange but true!  Differentiate your result and see if it is equal to the original integrand.

Comment: @GEdgar, that checks the result, but it doesn't verify the work that leads to it. [But of course your comment is spot on.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae#Transcendental_functions) for some more general integrals like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use linearisation of powers of $\cos(ax)^n,\sin(ax)^n$ since it is easy to integrate $\sin(nax)$ or $\cos(nax)$.

For instance here $\begin{cases} 4\cos(ax)^3 = 3\cos(ax)+\cos(3ax)\\4\sin(ax)^3 = 3\sin(ax)-\sin(3ax)\end{cases}$

From which you get $$\int \sin(ax)^3=\frac 14\left(\dfrac{-3\cos(ax)}{a}+\dfrac{\cos(3ax)}{3a}\right)+C=\dfrac{\cos(ax)^3}{3a}-\dfrac{\cos(ax)}{a}+C$$

This technique is very efficient for small powers, because linearising is a time consuming operation since you need to develop $(\frac{e^{iax}+e^{-iax}}2)^n$ via binomial formula, and especially if after integration you want the result in the form of powers of $\cos,\sin$ you need to factorise it back from its linearised form.

For higher powers, your technique give a more direct induction formula as shown in the pdf linked by **clathratus**.